# What is the origin of the word "parlor"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

What is the origin of the word *parlor*, as in an old fashioned sitting room? I suspect it's French, but I'm missing a step to get to the meaning.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parlor  - just scroll down the page a bit.

Comment: Not to worry; I was starting to type an answer (and Googling for a citation to back myself up) when I realized that I'd just be re-stating what was already there.  So I figured I'd make it a comment instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The etymology is here:

> C13: from Anglo-Norman *parlur*,  from Old French *parleur*  room in convent for receiving guests, from *parler*  to speak; see parley

It is actually from French.
What's more, it was taken from the word "parler," to speak, which is quite fitting for a room in which you hosted your guests!

Comment: Thank you! That does add up, doesn't it?

Comment: And from the same French word "parler," we also get the word "Parliament"

Answer (score 0):

Parlor is the room where the funeral service was held, where guests would come to pay last respects to the deceased; thus the most showy room for receiving guests.
When the funeral was not held at the house, it was held at the "funeral parlor."
Early houses usually had two sitting rooms, since the "parlor" was the place for the dead, the other sitting room was for the living; thus, the "living room."